# ng-change event called for radio buttons that are created using ng-repeat the first time but not for second time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do you call updateRow method from the onchange of radio button event

When the radio button changes, I need to call the updateRow method every time but it's currently only calling it the first time.

**Html:**

```
<div ng-repeat="b in RS_BehaviorActions">
    <input id="{{b.name}}" type="radio" name="behavior" value="{{b.name}}" style="padding:10px;" ng-model="selBehaviorVal" ng-change="updateRow(obj, selBehaviorVal)" /><label>{{b.name}}</label>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
//on change of updateRow method need to push radio button value into json
$scope.updateRow = function ( obj, selectedItem) {
            $scope.selectedItem = selectedItem;
            $scope.existInArray = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.permissionArray.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.permissionArray[i].relationShip == $scope.relationShip) {
                    $scope.existInArray = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($scope.existInArray) {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.permissionArray.length; i++) {
                    if ($scope.permissionArray[i].relationShip == $scope.relationShip) {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //$scope.permissionArray.splice(index, 1);
                $scope.permissionArray[index].behavior = $scope.selectedItem;
            }
            else {
                $scope.permissionArray.push({ "relationShip": $scope.relationShip, "behavior": $scope.selectedItem });
            }
            console.log($scope.permissionArray);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ng-click` instead of using `ng-change`. If you post a jsFiddle it will be easier to give you an appropriate solution.

Comment: So obvious I didn't even think of it.